# Scriptural reference about avoiding non vegetarian food on every Hindu festival?

Tags: scripture, festivals, food

It is mentioned across Hindu scriptures to avoid non vegetarian food on certain days or months, which may include some festivals also.

But, is there any mention to not eat non vegetarian food on **every** Hindu festival?

Any counter example that allows to eat non vegetarian food on a festival day can be an answer.

Comment: But if I am not wrong, certain non-veg items like chicken are prohibited as we don't find reference of any such sacrifice being made during pujas. But there's reference of goat or male buffalo sacrifices during Kali puja. Pls throw some light on this.

Comment: @D.Chatterjee chicken and other bird meats are allowed by Tantras.Puranas do not generally allow that but there are exceptions.In hindu Devi worship, normally goat and bufallo are normally alliwed and none excdpt the outcastes eat buffalo meat even as prasad.

Comment: Those who downvoted, please tell a reason if possible.........

Answer (score 1):

**Any counter example that allows to eat non vegetarian food on a festival day can be an answer.**

Yes, I am providing one counter example.

Durga puja is the greatest festival of Bengal.Raghunandan Bhattacharya, a renowned smarta pundit and the writer of the Ashtavimshati-Tattva compiled the vidhis of Durga Puja which is followed here. He prescribes that many animals **should be**  on the Mahanavami day to Devi. I quote from Swami-Sishya-Samvad written on Swami Vivekakakda by His disciple Sri Saratchandra Chakraborty:

> During the first Durga Puja at Belurmath in 1901, Swamiji asked His disciple Sarat Chandra Chakrabarti to bring one copy of Ragunandan's book on Durga-Puja. After reading the book, Swamiji says to Saratchandra:
>
> If possible, we shall perform the worship of the Divine Mother this year. Raghunandan says: navamyaam pujayet devim krittva rudhira-kardamam (on Navamai tithi,Devi should be worshipped by creating a mud of animal blood). If the Divine Mother wishes, we will also do that.(Swami-Sishya-Samvad, Saratchandra Chakravarti,Udbodhan, page 229).

But the sacrifice did not take place because of Sri Sarada Devi's objection